# How to run sequence of spark command through bash

Tags: command-line

I want to enter into spark-shell using shell script and then execute below commands

```
cat abc.sh

spark-shell

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlcontext.read.json("/file/path")
```

i am able to enter into spark-shell scala but next two commands are not running

Or else kindly let me know how can i run sequence of spark commands in scala automatically using shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t start a sub shell and just list commands in the manner you have attempted. Presumably the shell is waiting for input from you.

Broadly speaking, you have two routes you can go down.  You would either need to feed `spark-shell` a file containing the commands you want it to run (if it supports that) or make use of input redirection. This answer addresses the latter option via a heredoc.

Amending your existing script as follows will probably do the trick.

```
spark-shell << EOF
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlcontext.read.json("/file/path")
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me :)

Comment: Also, let me know how to exit from script.post completion.it is not exiting.i used :q,:quit,exit().system.exit(0). but now working

Comment: The shell script in my answer would exit as soon as `spark-shell` returns control to it.  I don't know `spark-shell` at all, so I can't speak for how it behaves or exactly how you would make it exit.  That said, I would typically expect a shell that was receiving redirected output to close as soon as the stream of commands stopped (which is what the `EOF` represents in this context).